# How to cache column in table in laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code in my controller. It's work to cache a table name as `books`,
but I want to cache a column in this table. If the Cache is implemented in the controller, it will automatically be applied to the view pages?

```
public function index()
 {
    return $value = Cache::remember('books', 1, function(){
       return DB::table('books') ->get();
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
$value = Cache::remember('books',1,function(){
     return DB::table('books')->pluck('column_name');
});
```

Comment: thank you ..it works correctly..please i want to ask you if i cached a column in controller by this way above.. will be applying automatically the cache in blade pages??@hala

Comment: I don't think so. you should retrieve the value from cache and pass it to the blade

Comment: thank you very much ..I searched for a long time like this and could not find out... do you now way or part code to do this??@hala